# pyspark ml error -u'requirement failed: Cannot have an empty string for name'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a spark ml kmeans model with the below code and passing a dataframe to get the the clusters

```
def pre_process_data_for_kmean(dataframe):
    train_data = dataframe.select(col("custid"),col("amount").cast("double").alias("amnt"),col("trantype"),((col("trantime"))).cast("double").alias("date_time"))
    cat1Indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="custid", outputCol="indexedCat1", handleInvalid="skip")
    cat2Indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="trantype", outputCol="indexedCat2", handleInvalid="skip")
    cat1Encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="indexedCat1", outputCol="CatVector1")
    cat2Encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="indexedCat2", outputCol="CatVector2")
    cat3Encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol="date_time",outputCol="CatVector3")
    fAssembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["CatVector1","CatVector2","CatVector3","amnt"],
    outputCol="C5")
    cluster_model = KMeans(k=10, seed=1,featuresCol="C5")
    cluster_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[cat1Indexer, cat1Encoder,cat2Indexer,cat2Encoder,cat3Encoder,fAssembler])
    cluster_model = cluster_pipeline.fit(train_data)
    return cluster_model
```

I am passing the data frame as

```
  train_df = raw_train_df.select(col("dSc").alias("custid"),col("TranAmount").alias("amount"),col("TranDescription").alias("trantype"),func.dayofmonth(col("BusinessDate")).alias("trantime")).na.fill({'trantype':'new_tran_type','custid':'-99999','amount':0,'trantime':1}).dropna()

  cluster_model = pre_process_data_for_kmean(train_df)
```

Now I understand that oneHotEncoder does not accept empty string and I have already takes measures to counter that as you can see. but still I am facing this error

Please assist .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Empty string* is literally and empty string not `NULL`. Neither `na.fill` nor `dropna` will help. You can use `na.replace` but as far as I know it has not columnwise equivalent so you'll have to call it for each column:

```py
replacements = {
  'some_col': 'some_replacement', 'another_col': 'another_replacement',
  'numeric_column_wont_be_replaced': 1.0
}

for k, v in replacements.items():
    # We can replace string only if target is string
    # In Python 2 str -> basestring
    if isinstance(v, str):
        df = df.na.replace("", v, [k])
```

Comment: How to find out which is empty  when we have close to 1000 columns, or how we can handle it throughout dataframe without naming it individually